Let $g(x)=\lim_{r \to 0}{\left((x+1)^{r+1}-x^{r+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}}$. Calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}x$.

The function $g(x) = \lim_{r \to 0}{\left((x+1)^{r+1}-x^{r+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}}$ is defined for any positive real $x$. Calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}x$.

I do not know where to start.The expression reminded me of the definition of a derivative or something like that. But it seems that the idea of this task is different.

You haven't told us anything about what you have tried: that's why you're getting  close votes (not from me). You should try something: e.g., a bit of algebraic simplification? Then let us know what went wrong if you can't solve the problem.
